# Binding an each statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I wanted to bind each statement to the #container div how would I go about this?

Here is an example of the each statement im trying to code:

```
$.each($(".product-comment"), function (key, value) {

    var showmoreHtml = $(this).html();
    var showlessHtml = showmoreHtml.substr(0, 400);
    if (showmoreHtml.length > 400) {
        $(this).html(showlessHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>");
    } 
    $(this).on("click", ".product-comment-more", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-less'> (Show less)</a>");

});


$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlCreateReview,
    data: form_data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $(".tab-comment-holder").load(" .tab-comment-holder");
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the jquery function on your selector, call `.each()` and pass a `function`:

```
$("#container div").each(function() {
    //do something
    console.log($(this));
});
```

EDIT:

Apparently the `div` is "reloaded" in the callback of an AJAX. The solution is to make sure its items are properly initialized inside the callback. There is an .each() for this purpose, but it uses commands such as

```
$(this).on("click", ".product-comment-more", function (event) {
    //...
}
```

which creates a `click` handler for every tag having the class of product-comment-more each time, this means that if there are n such tags and a user happens to click on one of those, the click handler will be executed n times. It's better to create a single handler for each of them. `showmoreHtml` is not well defined.

Comment: I don;t get to the click bit when the div is reloaded with the load function as the showmorehtml does not put each comment into a substring presumably because its not binded, so therefore there is no show more or show less option. This is what im trying to do get the show more and show less to work so i can click on them. If you could make up your own scenario with how you would go about it then that would be appreciated.

Comment: @detinu20 please, create a JSFiddle.